# How to calculate an average profit per day with Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I made a spreasheet to follow the growth of my income. It include a script that save periodically what I've earned. Column A is DATES, Column B is how much.

**I want to calculate my daily average profit.**

So I went to substract yesterday to today and then make an average of all that data. But there is a problem along the way because my script is saving data many times a day (to ensure I get data, and to tack more precisely).

- I would like to **first calculate an average profit for each day individually** (C column on screenshot)
- Then **calculate the variation** (D column on screenshot)
- Then **average the variation**. (E column on screenshot)

[image: Here is the process I have in mind]

As my data are growing each day, I'm looking for a flexible way to do it. I think QUERY may be a way but I don't know how to do that. A script would work too I guess. Maybe with the FILTER formula...

What's your thoughts on that ?
Cheers,
NipthiAe.

Comment: This is hard to do with formulas. Would you be OK using Apps Script?

Comment: Yes, I would be ok, I was also looking with query but it is hard for me.

Comment: By the way, are they always in order?

Comment: The order is by date. Each day there is approximately 4 new line to keep the data update.

Comment: So yeah, it is always in order, sorry.

Comment: I just saw the Nabnub answer but isn't `Portfolio` the accumulated?

Comment: Yes and no, sometimes there is some loss so the portfolio fluctuate. For now, I'm really happy, I could find my daily average profit as well as my bests and worts days in term of $ and %. Really useful tool !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To calculate the daily profits you shouldn't make an average of the portfolio on each time. For example, if in a single day you have

| Portfolio |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |

The average would be `2.4` but that's not the day's profits. To calculate a day's profits you need to subtract the last value of the day with the last value of the day before. In this case, if the last value was 0, the answer is 4.

Here is how I would do this.

### Solution

#### Step 1: Find the value of the protfolio when closing the day

What we need to do is find the latest value of each day. The simplest way of doing so is to find the last entry (using the datetime) of the day. So to get the last datetime we can use (in my case added it to `D2`):

```
=query({A3:A, arrayformula(int(A3:A))}; "select max(Col1) where Col1 is not null group by Col2 label max(Col1) ''"; 0)
```

Let's unpack this formula:

```
{A3:A, arrayformula(int(A3:A))}
```

It's a 2 column array. The first column are the datetimes. The second column are only the dates. That relies on the fact that `int(datetime)` returns the number representing the day. Add `arrayformula` to get it for each datetime and you get the day for each one.

Then the query:

```
select max(Col1)
  where Col1 is not null
  group by Col2
  order by max(Col1)
  label max(Col1) ''
```

The trick here is to get the biggest (latest) datetime within a day. This can be achieved by selecting `max(datetime)` and grouping by date. Then we can add a filter for empty cells (`where Col1 is not null`) and order the result to ensure the correct ordering. Also remove the default label by adding `label max(Col1) ''` at the end.

#### Step 2: Get the last value

Now that we have the last datetime of the day we can use `vlookup` to get the value (on `E3`):

```
=arrayformula(if(D3:D<>""; vlookup(D3:D; A3:B; 2; false); ""))
```

As you can see it's a simple `vlookup` that was wrapped in an `if` to prevent getting an error on empty cells. `arrayformula` allows us to do it for each row in one formula.

#### Step 3: Getting the daily profit

Now that we have the latest value we only need to subtract the row with the previous one (on `F3`):

```
=arrayformula(if(E3:E100<>""; E3:E-offset(E3:E; -1; 0); ""))
```

`offset` allows us to use this formula without having to specify the number of rows. As always, `arrayformula` allows us to do it for all rows in a single formula and we filter empty rows.

#### Step 3: Total average

We can finally take the average:

```
=average(F3:F)
```

If you didn't start from 0, you should change it to start at the next value (`F4`) since the first value will be the accumulated until that point.

### References

- [QUERY (Google Editors Help)](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343)
- [VLOOKUP (Google Editors Help)](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318)
- [ARRAYFORMULA (Google Editors Help)](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275)
- [OFFSET (Google Editors Help)](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093379)
- [IF (Google Editors Help)](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364)
- [INT (Google Editors Help)](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093490)

Comment: WoW ! I wasn't expecting such precision ! Plus it made my daily average way more than what I had before ! 
Thank you !!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with 3 formulas:

[image]

**First (query) in `D2`:**

To get the average per day

```
=query({A2:B}, 
   "Select Col1 ,count(Col1), avg(Col2) where Col1 is not null 
        group by Col1 Order By Col1 asc 
           label Col1 'Date', count(Col1) 'Days', avg(Col2) 'Average/day'")
```

**Second in `G4`:**

To get the differences between the averages obtained by the Query:

```
=arrayformula(if(isblank(E4:E6),"",filter(E4:E6,E4:E6>-1)-filter(E3:E6,E3:E6>-1)))
```

**Third (above the query) in `F1`:**

To get the average of the variations:

```
="Variation Avg: "& DOLLAR(round(AVERAGE(F3:F),2))
```

Comment: I have a problem with the Column D: On your screenshot there is one line by date, but on my spreadsheet, there is a line for each intraday. I would like to average like you do and if possible I'd like it to be on the same line as the line of the original date.

Comment: Thank you, I worked around and find my way ! It was worth it !
Again, thank you for your help !

Comment: You're welcome. If you want the demo sheet let me know. I've updated my answer to include the number of days for each date which could be useful. I was not really convinced by the format you're looking for.