# Average profit per day formula in 1 single cell

Tags: sorting, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, average, spreadsheet

I want to use the solution explained here:

[How to calculate an average profit per day with Google Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67003573/how-to-calculate-an-average-profit-per-day-with-google-sheets)

But in just a single cell instead of having to use 4 different cells for the calculation.

I came up with this formula but it seems to me too complicated and inefficient:

```
=AVERAGEIF((arrayformula(if((arrayformula(if(query({A2:A, arrayformula(int(A2:A))}, "select max(Col1) where Col1 is not null group by Col2 label max(Col1) ''", 0)<>"", vlookup(query({A2:A, arrayformula(int(A2:A))}, "select max(Col1) where Col1 is not null group by Col2 label max(Col1) ''", 0), {A2:A,C2:C}, 2, false), "")))<>"", (arrayformula(if(query({A2:A, arrayformula(int(A2:A))}, "select max(Col1) where Col1 is not null group by Col2 label max(Col1) ''", 0)<>"", vlookup(query({A2:A, arrayformula(int(A2:A))}, "select max(Col1) where Col1 is not null group by Col2 label max(Col1) ''", 0), {A2:A,C2:C}, 2, false), "")))-QUERY((arrayformula(if(query({A2:A, arrayformula(int(A2:A))}, "select max(Col1) where Col1 is not null group by Col2 label max(Col1) ''", 0)<>"", vlookup(query({A2:A, arrayformula(int(A2:A))}, "select max(Col1) where Col1 is not null group by Col2 label max(Col1) ''", 0), {A2:A,C2:C}, 2, false), ""))), "SELECT * offset 1", 0), "")*-1)),">0")
```

Dummy file is here, formula is on `D4`:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ExXtmQ8nyuV1o_UtabVJ-TifIbORItFMWjtN6ZlruWc/edit?usp=sharing

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(AVERAGE(QUERY(IFNA(QUERY(
 INDEX(SORTN(SORT({INT(A3:A), C3:C}, ROW(A3:A), ), 9^9, 2, 1, 1),,2),  "offset 1", )-
 INDEX(SORTN(SORT({INT(A3:A), C3:C}, ROW(A3:A), ), 9^9, 2, 1, 1),,2)), "offset 1", )))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you that is correct and works. How would I go about making the average respond to a data validation cell where I choose for the formula to give me an avg according to my choice: last 3 days, last 7 days, last month and so on? I have this here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ExXtmQ8nyuV1o_UtabVJ-TifIbORItFMWjtN6ZlruWc/edit . Cell on the right is responsive to the data validation cell but the average is wrong. I can't figure out how to combine the 2: make the left one with your formula responsive to data validation.

Comment: I have created a question for this: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ExXtmQ8nyuV1o_UtabVJ-TifIbORItFMWjtN6ZlruWc/edit?usp=sharing